# Dynamically change name displayed when dynamic picklist value changed

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an object called VF_Page_Update__c where I have a Text field VF_Page_Value__c. Here I am dynamically populating the names of some VF Pages.
For ex. for VF_Page_Update__c Record 1, VF_Page_Value__c is VF1, for record 2, VF_Page_Value__c is VF2. So in the visualforce page, VF1 and VF2 are shown as a picklist.
My requirement is: whichever VF Page value I should choose in the page, only that name should automatically display on the page, so that I can do further actions on the specified page such as Edit etc. Can you please help regarding this? Currently, only the page name corresponding to the particular record id provided in URL is getting displayed. I want that when the dynamic picklist value is changed, the name displayed should change too.

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class Test_Update_Controller  {
public String city{get; set;}
private final VF_Page_Update__c speaker; 
public String updatebody {get; set; } 
public Test_Update_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) 
{ 
this.speaker =(VF_Page_Update__c)stdController.getRecord(); }
public List<SelectOption> getcitynames() 
{   
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();   List<VF_Page_Update__c> citylist= new List<VF_Page_Update__c>();   citylist = [Select Id,VF_Page_Value__c FROM VF_Page_Update__c ];   options.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));   for (Integer
j=0;j<citylist.size();j++)   {
options.add(new SelectOption(citylist[j].VF_Page_Value__c,citylist[j].VF_Page_Value__c));
}   
return options; }   
public PageReference saveClose() { update speaker;

     return null;
         }
 public List<ApexPage> getPages()
    {
    updatebody =[select VF_Page_Picklist__c, Update__c, VF_Page_Value__c from VF_Page_Update__c WHERE id =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ORDER BY CreatedDate].VF_Page_Value__c;
     return[Select Id,name from ApexPage where name=:updatebody];
     }
     }
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="VF_Page_Update__c" extensions="Test_Update_Controller" >
  <apex:form id="form1">
<apex:sectionHeader title="VF Page Creation & Updation" subtitle="Create and Update values"/>
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="VF Page Selection" columns="1">
<apex:pageblocksectionItem >
 <apex:outputlabel value="Name of VF Page" for="values" />
          <apex:selectList value="{!city}" size="1" id="values">

              <apex:selectOptions value="{!citynames}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlocksectionItem>
</apex:pageBlocksection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:form id="form2">
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Pages}" var="c">
    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" />

    </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Select blocks of code and hit the curly brace button (`{}`) or hit `CTRL+K` to format them.

Comment: What part of you code do you think should be making the name change?

Comment: When I select a VF page name in the dynamic picklist, then in the section below, I want the specific name displayed.<apex:form id="form2">
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Pages}" var="c">
    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" />    This part is showing the name from the dynamic picklist.